# Redacting files of Django project after deplo

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I have deployed my Django project on my local server.
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Django 4.2.4
nginx 1.18.0
gunicorn 20.1.0
I use mysql-connector-python to connect with MySQL database.
mysql-connector-python 8.0.33

I need to redact file with my DB queries and setting.py. I try to redact with nano and restart nginx but it doesn't work. How can I redact this files on prod?

Comment: restart gunicorn, not nginx